# zend routes ini load routes by order according to priority.

Tags: zend-framework

Zend Project with multiple modules and every modules have its own routes.ini defined inside it. and every routes.ini file is being loaded using following script in module based bootstrap files.

```
 protected function _initRoutes() {
            $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
            $router = $frontController->getRouter();
            $routerDir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)). "/configs/routes/moduleRoutes.ini";
            $config = new Zend_Config_Ini($routerDir,'production');
            $router->addConfig($config,'routes');
    }
```

and All routes are being loaded without order. because Routes are checked in reverse order of loaded sequence and it check/execute those routes first which it should check/execute later.

Is there a way that I can add a orderBy bit (1,2,3,4...) with every route in routes.ini file of each module and load them in specific order so that It will check the routes in sequence I define.

typical routes.ini file of modules looks like this.

```
routes.frontindex.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.frontindex.route = "/?(?!login/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([0-9_-]+)?"
routes.frontindex.defaults.module = mymodule1
routes.frontindex.defaults.controller = mycontroller1
routes.frontindex.map.page = 1

routes.siteimage.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.siteimage.route = "siteimage/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?(jpg|png|gif)?"
routes.siteimage.defaults.module = mymodule1
routes.siteimage.defaults.controller = mycontroller2
routes.siteimage.defaults.action = getimage
routes.siteimage.map.imageid = 1


routes.sitemapseo.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.sitemapseo.route = "sitemap.xml"
routes.sitemapseo.defaults.module = mymodule1
routes.sitemapseo.defaults.controller = mycontroller3
routes.sitemapseo.defaults.action = sitemap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, but it will take some work and you'll need to be fairly comfortable with ZF.

You'll need to extend `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite` to make your own router class (which you will need to set using the front controller's setRouter() method in the bootstrap). In your router class, you'll want to:

- Extend the `addRoute` method to add a third parameter indicating priority. (This could be a constant like `Your_Router::HIGH_PRIORITY`, `Your_Router::MEDIUM_PRIORITY` etc. or simply a number). You'll see that the existing method stores routes in an array called `_routes`. You could instead store routes in different array depending on the priority param (`$this->_highPriorityRoutes`, `$this->_lowPriorityRoutes` etc.)
- Extend the `route()` method. Most of that unfortunately will be cut and paste. But you'll see that it calls `array_reverse` on `$this->_routes` and then loops though these to do the matching. You'll want to merge together your route arrays so that the end result is an array with your highest priority routes first. So you might end up with something like:

  ```
  $routes = array_merge($this->_lowPriorityRoutes, $this->_highPriorityRoutes);
  $routes = array_reverse($routes, true);

  foreach ($routes as $name => $route) {
      (...as before)
  ```
- Update your ini files to add a parameter to your routes indicating the priority. Then extend the `addConfig()` method in the router class so it passes this parameter to the `addRoute()` method.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can specify an order.  You'd have to write your own code to do this.  I'm sure there's multiple ways, but have you considered writing a custom [Zend Controller Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html)?  You could make one and assemble your routes inside the `routeStartup()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to set a priority to the routes in application.ini.

For it I readed the code of `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite`. The important functions are `addRoute()` and `route()`. My conclusion is very simple : The routes are evaluated in the oposit order compare the order in application.ini.

**Example :**

If I write in application.ini

*routeA*

*routeB*

*routeC*

*routeC* will be checked first, and *routeB* after and *routeA* the last.

priority *routeC* > priority *routeB* > priority *routeA*